# Reactor concatMap and OutputStream thread safety

Tags: spring, spring-boot, project-reactor

General context is some flux pipeline retrieving data from an API via `.flatMap` and then writing it into a file.

Can I "simply" use `.concatMap` to prevent several threads from accessing/writing into a shared `OutputStream`? As`.concatMap` is essentially sequential, do I have to deliberately publish on single thread within my pipeline or i.o.w do I still have to ensure thread-safety?

ChatGPT for reactive context suggested to use classic lock within reactive context ... alternatively suggested to use `Schedulers.elastic()` (probably meant `.single`) and finally `AsynchronousFileChannel` (which I never used).

Ultimately, my desire is to have some reactive paradigm in order to address this which wouldn't smell.

My understanding is that using `.concatMap` kills any parallelisation and is elegant way to avoid messing with locks or dispatching work explicitly to single thread.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: concatMap is the right tool, yes. Normally, there should be a *happen before* guarantee that make single thread scheduling unnecessary, but I am not 100% sure. Note that Springframework provides [DataBufferUtils.write(Publisher<DataBuffer>, OutputStream)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/55d13a02328752addaa59192776d93b7004fc2f1/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/io/buffer/DataBufferUtils.java#L261) method, and it does not make or talk about any additional synchronisation or scheduling constraint, so it may be safe to use "as is".

Comment: @amanin thanks for suggestion, just to complete your comment if anyone else decides to follow this path, the method .write will use WritableByteChannel which allows only one write at a time effectively blocking. This could provide safety if flux concatMap doesn't respect happen before guarantee. To get DataBuffer use         DataBufferFactory dataBufferFactory = new DefaultDataBufferFactory(); -> .wrap(bytes[])